# Allow access from specific referer only on a specific time in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using this code in my htaccess file to block traffic from specific websites to my website and it works:

```
RewriteEngine On
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "example.com" bad_referer
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from ALL
Deny from env=bad_referer
```

Now what I want is set a time for this code, for example, visitors from a specific website are only allowed to visit my website from 08:00 till 17:00

I tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN} >0800
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN} <1700 
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer " example.com " bad_referer
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from ALL
Deny from env=bad_referer
```

But does not seem to work, visitors are still blocked between the set time stamp

Thanks

Robert

Comment: Can’t expect things to “work”, if they don’t make much sense in the first place. `RewriteCond` influences whether a following `RewriteRule` gets applied or not, that is all this directive does. You do not even have a `RewriteRule` here.

Comment: I don’t think you can easily do > / < comparisons using SetEnvIf, I would do the whole thing using mod_rewrite. A RewriteCond to check the referrer, plus RewriteConds that check if the time is outside of your allowed window - and if those all match, deny access via a simple Rule that uses the [`[F]` flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_f).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `SetEnv`  with `RewriteRule` as these two directives are part of two different apache modules.  You can use `mod-rewrite` to achieve what you want to :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN} >=0800
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN} <=1700
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=403,L]
```

Comment: Wow thanks this is what I needed, I am still learning this helps a lot!